# How can one justify that $\|(I - \mu\mu^T)x\|_2 = \|(I - \mu\mu^T)\|_2\|x\|_2$ where $\mu$ is from the tangent-normal decomposition of the vector $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Full-details about the context of the tangent-normal decomposition are present [in this blogpost](https://dlwhittenbury.github.io/ds-2-sampling-and-visualising-the-von-mises-fisher-distribution-in-p-dimensions.html) (search for tangent-normal decomposition). Let $x, \mu$ be $p$-dimensional vectors on the unit sphere.

What I'm interested in hearing is how we could argue about $\|(I - \mu\mu^T)x\|_2$ a vector norm being equal to $\|(I - \mu\mu^T)\|_2\|x\|_2$, a product between an operator and a vector norm? It does make sense if $x$ is a unit vector (it is) which maximizes $\|Ax\|_2$ for $A = I - \mu\mu^T$. But I don't know how to tie the geometric interpretation of $x$ in the tangent-normal decomposition to this.

Comment: I think there's some important part of the context missing. $I-\mu\mu^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $\mu$, so it has norm $1$ (if $p\neq 1$), but $(I-\mu\mu^T)x$ can easily have norm less than $1$ (it's zero if $x=\mu$).

Comment: @MaoWao Do you mean that my written question lacks some important context? Or that there is some important context missing in the blogpost I linked? That blog post essentially supplements one section of the book *Directional Statistics, Kanti V. Mardia, Peter E. Jupp (pp.159-173)*. Besides those two sources, I couldn't find anything else about this question.

Comment: For me, the conclusion of the blog post $\lVert I-\mu\mu^T\rVert=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ does not make sense. The $t$ on the right side is defined as $t=x\cdot\mu$, which depends on $x$, while the left side is independent of $x$ (unless there are some hidden dependencies on the definitions of $x$ and $\mu)$. That's why I asked for more context.